# Сессия выдаёт старое значение

Tags: php

Почему $_SESSION['ИМЯ'] может выдавать старое значение, то есть запаздывает на один шаг? В чём особенности?

Answer (score 1):

Особенности в том, что $_SESSION['ИМЯ'] может быть задано после того как было прочитано.

Например:

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['ИМЯ'];
//...some code
$_SESSION['ИМЯ'] = database_get_value('ИМЯ');

//database_get_value - функция получения значения из ДБ. Предположим, пользователь ее где-то описал.
```

Comment: Дело в том, что сессия у меня в другом файле, а к нему обращение идёт через src. И поэтому приходится работать только через суперглобальные переменные SESSION. А они почему-то запаздывают.